# Attribute Error, Type Error, Name Error While trying to print simple JSON from server response?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api

I am trying to get JSON and print VIA python scirpt. I got response from server 200, not sure why i can not able print the file. Please help me on this!!

The Code used is:

```
Import Requests
response = requests.get("https://Site1/rest/settings/all-server-status", params={'serverId': '56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674'}, verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

I got below error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I tried below statements also but no response:

```
json_data = json.loads(response)
json_data = json.loads(response.read())
```

The Json Sample output expecting is:

```
[{"id":"56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674","protocol":"https","hostName":"x.x.x.x","port":443,"serverName":"Site1","status":"connected","connected":true}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you ensure that the server is in fact returning valid json? try printing the response and running it through a JSON validator: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes it is!! Valid Json.

Comment: you may need to use : response.json()

Comment: Sorry I got this error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Folks, Any comment on this!

Comment: Folks, Please help me on this i used these statements `json_data = json.loads(response)`, `response.json()` , `json_data = json.load(response)` , `json_data = json.load(response.json())` , `json_data = json.loads(response.text)`.. No luck please help me on this

Comment: could you paste the result: response.text here?

Comment: While i am trying to print, I can not able to print, I got the above error. But when i use this statement `json_data = json.dumps(response)` i got this error `TypeError: <Response [200]> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: No, it's not valid JSON document. `response.json()` should return parsed data, but only when `response.text` **is** valid JSON. Yours not. Note that _empty_ response is still *invalid* JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The POST request you are making is not returning anything, however the `Response 200` indicates the connection was successful(No SSL error etc).

The problem is here: `params={'serverId': '56cd7e4d2d0edcace915e674'}`.

I would suggest debugging your `request.get()`.

Start by checking if the `https://hostname.com/key=value` is valid.